# MySQL set OFFSET depending on subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete all records older than one week while keeping at least one for each user.
Example:

```
| ID | user |   date   | other columns...
|  1 | 1234 | -2 days  | ...    
|  2 | 1234 | -3 days  | ...
|  3 | 1234 | -8 days  | ...
|  4 | 5678 | -9 days  | ...
|  5 | 5678 | -10 days | ...
```

Should become

```
| ID | user |   date   | other columns...
|  1 | 1234 | -2 days  | ...    
|  2 | 1234 | -3 days  | ...
|  4 | 5678 | -9 days  | ... // Keeping the most recent record for this user
```

So far I've made this, but it uses CASE to set OFFSET, so it doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM transactions WHERE ID < (
  SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID FROM transactions t WHERE
    DATE(date) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
    user = transactions.user 
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT ID FROM transactions x WHERE
      DATE(date) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
      user = transactions.user
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  )
)
```

So the question is: how to fix the code above?

P.S.: I'm relatively new to anything except most basic operations in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *grouping* the transactions by user, you can determine those that you wish to preserve:

```
SELECT   user, MAX(date) date
FROM     transactions
GROUP BY user
```

You can then make an outer join between these results and your original table using the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax in order to delete only the desired records:

```
DELETE transactions
FROM   transactions NATURAL LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT   user, MAX(date) date
         FROM     transactions
         GROUP BY user
       ) t
WHERE  date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND t.date IS NULL
```

Comment: Two problems: a) I don't understand how should this work, b) It doesn't work (nothing gets deleted even if I remove that interval - everything should match when compared with current date). But thanks for your time anyway

Comment: I'm sorry for telling the opposite ;) The problem was that my table uses a bit different column names and I didn't realize that in `MAX(date) date` even the second `date` must be "translated". Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Markaos: Yes, the reason for that is that a `NATURAL JOIN` is performed on matching column names—so if the aliased name of the second column in table `t` doesn't match the name of the `date` column in `transactions` then the join won't be performed properly.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELETE FROM transactions tt WHERE tt.id NOT IN (
SELECT ID FROM transactions t WHERE
    DATE(t.date) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
    t.user = tt.transactions.user 
    ORDER BY t.ID DESC limit 1
)
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This gives me "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery". I tried wrapping it in another subquery (`SELECT * FROM (<subquery>)`), but then it says transactions.user doesn't exist. Also with alias "tt" on first row, it stops executing there with "Syntax error"